# Could I emulate Win 7 on Win 10

Tags: emulator

I'm running Win 10 Pro.
I was using application that supports only Win 7 hence when I connect USB device and start the application it states that can't recognize USB device.
My question: does Win 10 have the option to 'emulate' Win 7 ?

thanks

Comment: Why can't you use a Windows 7 virtual machine?  Windows 10 Professional has Hyper-V built-in, you can create a Hyper-V virtual machine, and install Windows 7 provided you have a license for it.

Comment: Well ... the problem is that I don't have a license for Win 7

Comment: If you do not have a license for Windows 7 then you cannot run it within a virtual machine, that is the only way to run an application that only supports Windows 7, on a machine running Windows 10.

Comment: Just a quick thought in relation to my answer below, does your Windows 10 machine recognise your USB stick successfully?  It's just the application you are running that doesn't recognise the USB stick?

Comment: @james. It is probably not a USB stick, but some sort of external device that uses USB for programming purposes. Many Eprom programmers and development boards fall in that category. And often their software dates from the Windows XP days and there isn't any modern alternative.

Comment: @Tonny that's a good point, something I didn't think about actually.  Would be interesting to find out from susik, we can edit the original question to make it more specific incase anyone else comes across this later on :)

Comment: @james .. USB drive is OK and recognizable by Win 10. Just Application that uses USB fails to recognize device ..

Comment: @susik Any software (regardless how old) should see a USB drive as a normal drive. Unless the program tries to access some hidden part of the drive in some non-standard way. In that case: Did you try running the program in "Run as Administrator mode" ? That would most definitely be required on Windows 10 in order to do something like that.

Comment: well .. now I'm not positive that the issue in my case is caused by OS incompatibility :) .. Here's what happened ... I could connect one device to my HP Elitbook running Win 10 Pro and it get recognized and operates well. When I add another device ... I've got message that USB device was not recognized. Then I checked that this device is supported up to Win 7 hence I decided the issue is with OS. Now I'm thinking that maybe the issue is with USB ... not sure ... any thoughts ?

Comment: @susik  could you please share the information of what the usb device is?

Answer (score 2):

Windows 10 has a handy tool that might be able to help you here @susik.

Search for the Program Compatibility Troubleshooter on your Windows 10 machine.  When you run this, you will then be able to select the program that is causing you issues, and it will see if there is anything it can do.

During this process, you will be able to select the operating system you want to emulate for this application.

More details on this can be found here: http://www.laptopmag.com/articles/set-compatibility-mode-windows-10

If that doesn't work, there is the option to manually set the compatibility mode.  If you **right-click** on the application shortcut and click **Open File Location**. 
In the new explorer window, the application executable will be highlighted.  At this point, **right-click** on that file & click **properties**.

Select the **Compatibility** tab, then place a tick in the **compatibility mode** box.  Finally, select the operating system you want to emulate, in this case **Windows 7**.

Apply and OK the properties and try running the application again.
More information on that process is here: https://support.microsoft.com/en-gb/help/15078/windows-make-older-programs-compatible

HTH

Comment: Extra tip: It sometimes helps to set the compatibility level even lower than you actually think you need. E.g set it to Vista or even XP. This might be especially useful for applications that work on Windows 7, but that where designed for even older versions of Windows.

Comment: Thanks for info. I'll try to play with it and will update you later ...

Comment: Well here's what I found: Vendor of the device confirmed that it's not supported by Win 10 and they don't have new drivers. When I connect the device to computer ... not even started application yet ... I've got error message that USB was not recognized. Hence when I start application I've got message that it's not connected to device. Based on the above ... it looks playing with Win 7 compatibility for application won't work in this case. I'm intended to give it up ... unless you have other ideas ... Thanks

Comment: I've done this with an exe I built and it worked with this compatibility troubleshooter but not in a VM with the same XP service pack 3 so this is probably not that trustworthy. I think a VM is the way to go.

Answer (score 0):

Well ... I was confirmed by the Vendor of the device that current drivers are not supposed to work with Win 10.
Hence trying to emulate Win 7 for that device will not help me (IMO) because the issue starts Not when I launch application but when I simply insert device into PC.
I decided to give up with it ...
Thanks for trying to help

Answer (score -2):

the window emulator fixed MathCAD 14 to run on Win 10 for me. The guys at PTC didn't bother to tell me it was an option either. Hardly a surpise with that outfit.